# Getting a multidimensional array with the 'returningFeval' method in matlabcontol

Tags: java, arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

I'm using matlabcontrol to control Matlab remotely with Java, is there a way to get a multidimensional numeric array out of the Object array returned to Java from the `returningFeval` method? 
The `returningFeval` method returns an Object array and my Object[0] is a Matlab 2-D Array of doubles.

For example:

```
MatlabProxyFactory factory = new MatlabProxyFactory();
MatlabProxy proxy = factory.getProxy();

Object[] myData = proxy.returningFeval("myFunction", 2, "Arg");
double[][] a2DArray = myData[0];
```

This returns:

```
ClassCastException: "[D cannot be cast to [[D."
```

I know I can get the array using the `MatlabTypeConverter` class and the `.getNumericArray` method, but then I wouldn't be doing anything with the returned `'myData[0]'`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Arrays.copyOf() method can be used to convert Object arrays into arrays of other types without ClassCastExceptions if they are really compatible.

```
Double[][] integerArray = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length, Double[][].class);
```

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(U[],%20int,%20java.lang.Class)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28U%5b%5d,%20int,%20java.lang.Class%29)

Answer (score 0):

Matlab uses one dimensional indexing and returns a `double[d1*d2*...*dk]` array. In order to convert this array to `double[d1][d2]...[dk]` the values of d1 ... dk should be known. The following code do the rest:

```
 private static Object unflattenMatrix(boolean columnwise, double[] data, int... dimensions) {
    Object res = Array.newInstance(double.class, dimensions);
    List<Integer> dims = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < dimensions.length; i++) {
        dims.add(dimensions[i]);
    }

    if (columnwise) {
        Collections.reverse(dims);
    }
    setTraversingColumnwise(res, data, new LinkedList(), dims, columnwise);
    return res;
}

static private int counter;

private static void setTraversingColumnwise(Object res, double[] data, List<Integer> indices, List<Integer> dimensions, boolean columnwise) {
    if (indices.isEmpty()) {
        counter = 0;
    }
    if (dimensions.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(indices.toArray()));
        setInDoubleArray(res, indices, data[counter++], columnwise);
    } else {
        int d = dimensions.remove(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < d; i++) {
            indices.add(i);
            setTraversingColumnwise(res, data, indices, dimensions, columnwise);
            indices.remove(indices.size() - 1);
        }
        dimensions.add(0,d);
    }
}

private static void setInDoubleArray(Object doubleArr, List<Integer> indices, double data, boolean reverse) {
    if (reverse) {
        indices = new LinkedList<>(indices);
        Collections.reverse(indices);
    }
    Object cur = doubleArr;
    Iterator<Integer> iter = indices.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        int indx = iter.next();
        if (iter.hasNext()) {
            cur = ((Object[]) cur)[indx];
        } else {
            ((double[]) cur)[indx] = data;
        }
    }
}
```

Sample usage :

```
    double[][] res =(double[][]) unflattenMatrix(false,
                     new double[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, new int[]{2, 4});
```